# How to make code-line dynamically increased based on the input data

Tags: c#

The title might be misleading, but not sure how to specify it more correctly.

I'm developing a code for Appium test, that should select a window element in the tree, and the tree path is dynamic.
How can I make my code to handle such case.

I.e. right now I have following code:

```
var treePath = new List<string>() {"Level_1", "Level_2", "Level_3"}; 

public void SelectElement(List<string> treePath)
{
 foreach (var item in treePath)
                    {
                        windowView.InventoryTree.GetElementByAccessibilityID("Root").GetElementByAccessibilityID(item)....Click();
                    }
}
```

The `.GetElementByAccessibilityID("Level_XX")` can vary from 1 to many, and what I want is the code-line before the .Click() to be dynamically increased, based on the number of levels in the `treePath`.

Thus it can be

```
windowView.InventoryTree.GetElementByAccessibilityID("Root").GetElementByAccessibilityID("Level_1").Click();
```

OR

```
windowView.InventoryTree.GetElementByAccessibilityID("Root").GetElementByAccessibilityID("Level_1").GetElementByAccessibilityID("Level_2").GetElementByAccessibilityID("Level_3").Click();
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to the outcome of each `GetElementByAccessibilityID` call, then when you're done, call `.Click()` on it.

```
var treePath = new List<string>() {"Level_1", "Level_2", "Level_3"}; 

public void SelectElement(List<string> treePath)
{
  var finalElement = windowView.InventoryTree.GetElementByAccessibilityID("Root");
  foreach (var item in treePath)
  {
    finalElement = finalElement.GetElementByAccessibilityID(item);
  }
  finalElement.Click();
}
```

This will call `GetElementByAccessibilityID` for every level in `treePath`.